# Does a var declared in function persist across multiple function calls?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new variable every function call, and push this new variable to a global array.

```
globalArr = [];

function addObj(objId){
    var newObj = {id: objId};
    globalArr.push(newObj);
}
```

Javascript's `Array.prototype.push` method will append a reference to `newObj` to `globalArr`.

Will I be creating unique objects for every call to `addObj()`? I think but am not completely sure that `newObj` will not persist across multiple calls. I want to make sure I am not pushing references to the same `newObj` every time I call `addObj`.

I have considered a solution like the following, but am not sure if it is necessary:

```
    function addObj(objId){
            var newObj = new anObject(objId);
            globalArr.push(newObj);
    }

   function anObject(objId){
        this.id = objId;
   }
```

Perhaps the problem I speak of doesn't even exist?

Comment: Every time you call *addObj*, a brand new execution context is created with a brand new instance of the local variable *newObj*. What gets pushed into *globalArr* is a reference to the object assigned to *newObj*. Whatever happens to the *newObj* variable after than doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newObj = {id: objId};
```

This line will guarantee you that its a new object pointing to a different memory address every time. The open and close curly brackets initialize a new object. So this part actually:

```
var newObj = {};
```

So yes, pushing that value into a global array every time the function is called will give you X number of new objects where X is the number of times you called the function. It will not be reference to the same object. As you said, that second example of code is not necessary to achieve what you want.

To answer the title of this question a variable declared in a function does not persist over multiple function calls. Its a locally scoped variable that is instantiated anew every time the function is called.